# Foursquare Venue information

Tags: foursquare

Hi I am using python/beautiful soup to scrap information from foursquare's XML
it seems that after a certain number is reached, I cannot access foursquare at all.
Does anyone know if I need an access token even if I'm not trying to develop anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapping foursquare content is prohibited ("You shall not (directly or indirectly)... harvest or scrape any Content from the Service;") and you probably triggered the protection mechanism guarding against developers doing this.

See the foursquare [Terms of Service](https://foursquare.com/legal/terms) for more details